# The open embedding of topoi $\operatorname{Mod}^{a}_{R,I}\to\operatorname{Mod}_R$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, arithmetic-geometry, topos-theory

All of the following comes from [these notes by Bhatt](http://www-personal.umich.edu/%7Ebhattb/teaching/mat679w17/lectures.pdf). I apologize for my inexperience with topoi.

Fix flat ideal $I\subset R$ such that $I^2=I$. Define the category $\operatorname{Mod}^{a}_{R,I}$ of almost modules to be the Serre quotient of $\operatorname{Mod}_R$ by those $I$-torsion $\operatorname{Mod}_{R/I}$.

Define

- the subcategory inclusion functor $j_!:\operatorname{Mod}^{a}_{R,I}\to\operatorname{Mod}_R$;
- the Serre quotient functor $j^*:\operatorname{Mod}_R\to\operatorname{Mod}^{a}_{R,I}$; and
- the coëxtension functor $j_*:\operatorname{Mod}^{a}_{R,I}\to\operatorname{Mod}_R:M\mapsto\operatorname{Hom}_R(I,M)$.

One notices two significant facts:

1. There's an adjunction triple $j_!\dashv j^*\dashv j_*$; and
2. The counit $f^* f_* \Rightarrow\operatorname{id}$ is an isomorphism;

which induces one's wonder on if there's an open geometric embedding of (ringed) topoi for which objects of $\operatorname{Mod}_R$ and $\operatorname{Mod}^{a}_{R,I}$ are quasi-coherent modules.

Also, recall (from SGA 4 or something, if someone can recall where it is please comment) that if one decomposes say a scheme $X$ into a pair of mutually complementary components $U,Z$, one open, open closed, one has

[image]

where the composition of any two consecutive morphisms in the same direction results in the zero functor. Surprisingly, one can "decompose" a topos over $\operatorname{Spec}R$ in a similar fashion:

[image]

where the three functors on the last are given by the usual [functors for change of rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_rings).

Moreover, Bhatt (pp. 21-22) and Gabber-Ramero (at p. 11) both mentioned that there supposes to exist an "almost topos" explaining these geometric phenomena; i.e., according to Bhatt, there supposed to be a "open subscheme" complementary to the closed $Z$, the localization on which results in $\operatorname{Mod}_{R/I}$.

**What is the "almost topos"?**

Actually, localizing a topos should result in another topos? But how do I get a handle on the site, or specifically on what $\bar{U}$ is?

Comment: If I am understanding your question correctly, I think the clearest place this type of material is written down is in Section 5 of this: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.1970.pdf

Comment: @AlexYoucis Oh it’s SGA 1 not 4 sure. But the point is that the category I was talking about isn’t really a category of module over anything — it’s a localization thereof. Wait… do you mean the theory of the overconvergent site that paper was talking about is a way to carry out the localization on a ringed topos?

Comment: @AlexYoucis BTW when I say localization I mean as in localizing (or as Gabriel would say, quotienting) a category with respect to a multiplicative system of morphisms, instead of the “zooming in” to an object in a site by making it terminal.